# PayPal Converting Sale transaction to Recurring Billing Profile results in Duplicate error

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, payflowpro

Using payflow .net dll I am trying to create a Recurring Billing Profile without forcing my clients to take on the PCI compliance burden of handling credit card data so here's what I'm currently doing...

1. get secure token
2. create sale transaction (record results)
3. Convert it to Recurring Billing Profile (starting in the future)

This all works however when PayPal tries to create a transaction using the RBP it gets Result Code 30, Duplicate, error 10536 - ...duplicate invoice id...   I'm not setting an invoice id anywhere in my code.  When in step 2 I create an authorization instead of a sale it works (although the trans type in the IPN ends up being "cart"???).  So I assume this is a problem with converting a sale to a RBP.  If that is not allowed then step 3 should stop me but it doesn't.  So is there a way around this problem?

**NOTE**:  When using Express Checkout with the paypalcoresdk and paypalmerchantsdk dlls I am able to create a sale transaction AND a RBP using the same token and it all works and the IPN tran type ends up being recurring_payment which is correct.

**NOTE 2**:  The best solution would be for PayPal to allow me to create an RBP using a secure token.  I have not been able to make that work.

**NOTE 3**:  The reason I'm not using an Authorization transaction is because this would result in the client having loads of Auth transaction in PayPal that they could Capture at anytime resulting in duplicate payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of this error , Login to your Paypal account , go to Profile --> My selling Tools --> Block Payments . Here you will see something like " Block the payments with same invoice id " , put it to "No" and save the settings . It should be fine afterwards .

Comment: I'll try this and see what happens tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **NOTE 3**

I have found that I can set up an Authorization transaction with an amount of 0.  Then in the transaction history it will have a status of Completed and no Capture button.  Then when converting this to a Recurring Billing Profile PayPal allows you to set a different amount.  I don't know if this imposes a limitation on the amount but my test of $500 worked.

Hope that helps someone

Comment: Yes definitely you can do Zero dollar authorization transaction which is meant for verifying the credit card ,there is no restriction on that . The only thing is some processor requires the  minimum authorization to be at least 1 dollar .In that case you will have to do 1 dollar authorization

Comment: I'm using PayPal as the processor.  If I use one dollar as an amount the Auth trans is going to be pending with a capture button right?

Comment: Correct . But in order to avoid that , you can void the authorization once you have created the recurring profile .